# how to use laravel's validation rule in custom validation rule?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, input

I have input `$data =['identifier' = 'xxxxxxxxxx'];`, and want to save the `encrypt($data['identifier'])` to the table `info` primary `id` column.

I've to validate before save it. Rule `unique:info, id` isn't suitable here, so I want to write a custom validation rule. And in the custom validation rule, I `encrypt()` the value first, then use the `unique` validation rule.

I know how to write a custom validation rule, but how to use the `unique` validation rule in my custom validation rule?

Comment: Does https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules not suffice?

Comment: @ceejayoz please read my question more. Here I'm not writing a custom validation rule. I want to extent the unique rule.

Comment: What is the initial value of `id`? does it `int` then it will be encrypted?!

Comment: In other words, what do you mean by "extend unique rule"? Unique is unique! i.e it checks your table for exactly the same value!

Comment: @SaidbakR the id is string type, and I need to encrypt the idenfitier then store here. Here I use extend may not proper, I need a validation rule that encrypt on the input value first, then do the same as unique.

Comment: @KrisRoofe You say "extend the unique rule". I say that's a custom validation rule. The `unique` rule is just a validation rule - you can make your own that mimics it with your specific requirements.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you.  Maybe I should change my question to how to use laravel's validation rule in custom validation rule is proper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules "unique" and "exists" use the DatabasePresenceVerifier class. So, you don't need to really extend the unique rule, just access this presence verifier. For instance:

```
Validator::extend('encrypted_unique', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    list ($table, $column, $ignore_id) = $parameters; // or hard-coded if fixed
    $count = $validator->getPresenceVerifier()->getCount($table, $column, encrypt($value), $ignore_id);
    return $count === 0;
});
```

Then you can use it as usual:

```
'identifier' => "encrypted_unique:table,column,$this_id"
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have A **ModuleRequest** that validates your inputs,you can write this method in this class

```
protected function validationData() 
{
    $all = parent::validationData();
    $all['email'] = encrypt($all['email']);
    return $all;

}
```

Comment: I know this works. I want to use this `encrypt()` in the validation rule as stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has Custom Validation Rules (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-rule-objects)
For example I have a table named clients who has two unique fields ecnrypt using Laravel's encryption services (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption) and because its encrypted, i can't aply the unique directive of validation method (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique). The fields are *code_client* and *email*

That's the reason of implements a Custom Validation Rules.
this Service has two methods: *passes* and *message*. The method *passes* take two variables: $attributes (take de field to validate) and $value (take de value of field), and return true or false. Te method *message* retrieve message in case of failure.

In clients example i mentioned, folow the next steps:

1. php artisan make:rule ValidateFieldsClients
2. in class that composer creates  ValidateFieldsClients, I have to declare a method for validate the fields in passes, I use this method for validate both fields (*code_client* and *email*).
3. next i complete de method message to retrieve the issue to user in views
4. additionally i declare a property $field to identify what´s the field it have the errors
5. The class ValidateFieldsClients example:

   ```
        /***/class ValidateFieldsClients implements Rule{protected $field; /**
        * Create a new rule instance.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function __construct()
       {                
       }

       /**
        * Determine if the validation rule passes.
        *
        * @param  string  $attribute
        * @param  mixed  $value
        * @return bool
        */
       public function passes($attribute, $value)
       {
           $clients = client::all();   
           $this->field = $attribute;

           foreach ($clients as $client ) {
               if ($value == Crypt::decryptString($client->$attribute)) return false;            
           } 

           return true;
       }

       /**
        * Get the validation error message.
        *
        * @return string
        */
       public function message()
       {
           return strtoupper($this->field).' exists, check.';
       }
   }
   ```
6. Then to validate I use Form Request Validation (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation)
7. php artisan make:request ClientRequest
8. And in the validate method of the recently created class:

   ```
   class ClientRequest extends FormRequest
   {   /**
        * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
        *
        * @return bool
        */
       public function authorize()
       {
           return true;  } 


   /**
    * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
    *
    * @return array
    */
   public function rules()
   {

       return [ 
           'code_client'=> ['required', new ValidateFieldsClients],                
           'email'=>['required', new ValidateFieldsClients],
       ];
   }
   ```
9. Finally in controller:

   ```
    public function store(ClientRequest $request)
           { $clientRequest = $request->validated();
               foreach ($clientRequest as $key => $client) {
                   $encryptedClient[$key] = Crypt::encryptString($client);
               };      client::create($encryptedClient+ [
               'idorga' => 1,
               'idcrea' => 1,
               'idmodifica' => 1
           ]);

           return redirect('clientes/create')->with('success', 'Registro creado correctamente');
           //return redirect('cuadros')->with('success', 'Registro exitoso!');
       }
   ```

Comment: If you have thousands of customers it will take very long to execute the validation